# Слетает Wi-Fi на ноутбуке с Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, wifi, network-manager

Ситуация следующая ...

Ноутбук с **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**. Доступ к интернету идёт через раздачу с телефона.

Иногда я отхожу с телефоном от ноута и интернет (на ноутбуке) пропадает, хотя сеть дотягивает такое расстояние + иконка в трее показывает, что всё Ok — всё подключено; однако ни в Chrome, ни в Firefox сайты не грузятся ... Пинг тоже не проходит, но, что самое интересное, Телеграм на ноуте работает как ни в чём ни бывало :)

Какие действия я предпринимал:

- отлючал-включал Wi-Fi на ноуте — *не помогло*
- отключал-включал раздачу/интернет на телефоне — *не помогло*
- перезапускал браузеры — *не помогло*
- делал Logout на ноуте — *не помогло*
- помогла только перезагрузка ноута

---

**Что это может быть за глюк и куда копать?**

---

[image: Wi-Fi Settings - IPv4]

Comment: То, что «дотягивает», совсем не означает, что это «дотягивание» обеспечивает хорошее качество связи. Телеграм потребляет маленький трафик и его, видимо, плохая связь вполне устраивает, а вот сайты работать с плохой связью не могут

Comment: Касательно «Пинг тоже не проходит» — а исходящие сообщения в телеграме отправляются?

Comment: @andreymal, я сейчас перезагрузился, поэтому проверить не могу, как проблема всплывёт в очередной раз, проверю.

Comment: Кстати, а вы пингуете домен или IP-адрес? Симптомы косвенно указывают на возможный отвал DNS-сервера, и в таком случае какой-нибудь ping google.com не будет работать из-за невозможности отрезолвить домен, а ping 8.8.8.8 может и заработает

Comment: @andreymal, а вот IP я не пинговал, только домен ...

Comment: фирмваре на вайфай проверь

Comment: @andreymal, да, вы правы, по домену не пингуется, а по IP проходит.

Comment: Значит, видимо, нужно продолжать исследование проблемы в сторону DNS. Посмотреть что в /etc/resolv.conf, попинговать упомянутые там IP-адреса, почитать resolvectl status и прочие такие действия в зависимости от настроек DNS в текущей системе

Comment: @andreymal, в общем это косяки из-за рабочего VPN и не связаны с Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в рабочем VPN и не связана с Ubuntu.